# I already Have pagination from server side rest api. How can I paginate that pagination in html table

Tags: html, angularjs

My Rest api already has serverside pagination . I want to paginate that api to html table How can I do that using angular js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [UI Bootstrap's pagination](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#pagination)